# ¿Cómo usar correctamente las variables globales?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, variables-globales

Resulta que tengo el siguiente código, el cual consiste en un menú, en el cual tengo una variable `nombre` y que si por ejemplo yo presiono la opción `1` el resultado en pantalla tendría que ser `Alex`, pero la opción 2 modifica esa variable, por lo cual si ejecuto la opción `2` me tendría que modificar la variable `nombre` a `Daniel`, pero a mi me pasa que cuando vuelvo a hacer la opción `1` el resultado en consola sigue siendo `Alex`, cuando lo esperado es `Daniel` porque en teoría su valor ya fue modificado cuando se ejecuto la opción `2`, y otra pequeña duda también es de que como no tengo constructor es correcto el uso del `self` antes de la variable?

```
class Valores(object):
    nombre = "Alex"
    
    def ponerNombre(self):
        global nombre
        self.nombre = "Daniel"
        print("Nombre modificado")
    
    def imprimiendo(self):
        print(self.nombre)

def menuDeOpciones():
    bandera = True
    while bandera:
        print("1. Mostrar nombre")
        print("2. Modificar nombre")
        print("3. Salir")
        opcion = input()
        
        objetoValores= Valores()
        if opcion == '1':
            objetoValores.imprimiendo()
        elif opcion == '2':
            objetoValores.ponerNombre()
        elif opcion == "3":
            bandera = False

menuDeOpciones()
```

Agradecería si alguien pudiera orientarme en lo que estoy fallando, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nombre` no es una variable global; es una variable de clase.

**Variables de clase**

Las variables de clase pertenecen a la clase, no a una instancia particular de esa clase.

Cuando dices

```
class Valores(object):
    nombre = "Alex"
```

significa que existe exactamente una copia de `nombre` sin importar cuantos objetos de la clase `Valores` crees.

Para referenciar una variable de clase, usas el nombre calificado *NombreDeClase.NombreDeVariable*, por lo que es posible usar el mismo nombre de variable en distintas clases; no hay conflicto.

Ejemplo:

```
class Valores:
    nombre = "Alex"
    def __init__(self):
        self.nombre = "Daniel"

persona1 = Valores()
persona2 = Valores()
print(persona1.nombre) => Daniel
print(persona2.nombre) => Daniel
print(Valores.nombre)  => Alex
```

**Variables globales**

Las variables globales se declaran fuera de cualquier función y/o clase.

Si sólo vas a usarla, sin asignarlas, no necesitas nada especial

```
nombre_empresa = "3 Claveles"

def funcion():
    print(nombre_empresa)

funcion() => 3 Claveles
```

Si quieres asignar a una variable global dentro de una función, debes declararla `global`

```
nombre_empresa = "3 Claveles"

def funcion():
    global nombre_empresa
    nombre_empresa = nombre_empresa.lower()
    print(nombre_empresa)

print(nombre_empresa) => 3 Claveles
funcion()             => 3 claveles
print(nombre_empresa) => 3 claveles
```

Si no la declaras `global`, entonces pasa a ser una variable local a la función, aun si tienen el mismo nombre

```
nombre_empresa = "3 Claveles"

def funcion():
    nombre_empresa = "Arbolito"
    print(nombre_empresa)

funcion()             => Arbolito
print(nombre_empresa) => 3 Claveles
```

Ojo: la palabra clave aquí es "asignar". No necesitas declararla global si la vas sólo a modificar: las operaciones con listas, diccionarios y otras estructuras son "modificaciones", no "asignaciones"

```
lista_empresas = []

def crear_empresa(nombre):
    lista_empresas.append(nombre)

crear_empresa("3 Claveles")
crear_empresa("Arbolito")
print(lista_empresas) => ['3 Claveles', 'Arbolito']
```

Una asignación es "nombre = valor"; el resto son modificaciones.

**Tu código**

Si quieres que `nombre` sea global, sacalo fuera de la clase:

```
nombre = "Alex"
class Valores(object):
    
    def ponerNombre(self):
        global nombre
        self.nombre = "Daniel"
        print("Nombre modificado")
```

aunque en realidad el código que muestras no tiene sentido, ya que nunca usas `nombre` en ninguna parte del código. La línea

```
self.nombre = "Daniel"
```

hace referencia a una variable de instancia, particular al objeto:

```
nombre = "Alex"

class Valores(object):
    def ponerNombre(self, nuevo_nombre):
        self.nombre = nuevo_nombre

persona1 = Valores()
persona2 = Valores()
persona1.ponerNombre("Pepe")
persona2.ponerNombre("María")
print(persona1.nombre) => Pepe
print(persona2.nombre) => Maria
print(nombre)          => Alex
```

**Usos de las variables globales**

En general, hay que evitar el uso de variables globales por razones prácticas. Hace difícil razonar/entender un código cuando no saben donde o cuando se modifica dicha variable. Puedes confundirte y reutilizar la misma variable con otro contenido, introduciendo errores en la ejecución.

¿Qué uso tienen las variables globales? Normalmente para declarar valores inmutables de uso común dentro de un programa. Por ejemplo, la zona horaria, el servidor que usaras, la red WiFi a la que te conectas, etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Un poco de teoría

Tienes un pequeño lío de conceptos. Tu programa (al menos el trozo que muestras) no tiene variables globales.

Una variable global es una variable creada (inicializada) fuera de una función, método o clase. El símbolo `nombre` que inicializas con "Alex" está creado (inicializado) dentro de una clase, (aunque fuera de sus métodos). Eso la convierte en un **atributo de clase**.

Por otro lado en `ponernombre()` haces `self.nombre="Daniel"`, lo que crea un **atributo de instancia**.

Así pues tienes un atributo de clase y un atributo de instancia llamados igual, `nombre`. Las diferencias entre un atributo de clase y uno de instancia son:

- El atributo de clase se inicializa fuera de los métodos de la clase, mientras que el atributo de instancia se inicializa dentro de alguno de sus métodos, usando `self.atributo=loquesea` Lo más habitual es que se creen dentro de `__init__()` pero realmente podrían crearse en cualquier método de la clase.
- El atributo de clase existe en la clase (puedes acceder a él mediante `Valores.nombre`), mientras que el atributo de instancia existe sólo en los objetos de esa clase (en tu caso sería `objetovalores.nombre`). Al atributo de instancia también puedes acceder usando `self.atributo` si estás dentro de uno de sus métodos, pues dentro de los métodos el símbolo `self` representa al objeto (instancia).
- El atributo de clase existe desde el momento que declaras la clase. El atributo de objeto en cambio existe sólo a partir de que se crea, es decir, después de que se ejecute la línea con `self.atributo=loquesea`.
- Si tienes sólo un atributo de clase (y no un atributo de instancia), entonces al intentar leer del atributo de instancia accederás al de la clase. Es decir, en tu caso, si conservas la incialización `nombre = "Alex"` en la clase, pero quitas lo de `self.nombre="Daniel"` en el método, entonces un objeto de la clase `Valor` no tendría atributo `nombre` de instancia. Si creas un objeto: `o = Valor()` e intentas acceder a `o.nombre` para leerlo, ya que el objeto no tiene ese atributo, *se usará el de la clase*, es decir `o.nombre` nos llevaría a `Valor.nombre` y saldría "Alex". Lo mismo si dentro del objeto intentas leer de `self.nombre` y ese atributo no existe en el objeto: se buscará en la clase.
- Por tanto si tienes un atributo de clase, todos los objetos que crees de esa clase podrán acceder a ese atributo sin inicializarlo (pues está inicializado en la clase) y todos los objetos verían el mismo valor al leerlo.
- Pero si un objeto crea un atributo de objeto del mismo nombre (haciendo `self.atributo=otracosa`, entonces el atributo de objeto "tapa" al de clase. Esto es lo que ocurre en tu caso cuando haces `self.nombre = "Daniel"`. A partir de este momento tienes dos atributos con el mismo nombre (el de clase y el de instancia) y cuando accedas a `self.nombre` estarás accediendo ya siempre al de instancia. La única forma a partir de aquí de acceder al de la clase es poner `Valor.nombre`.

Tu programa tiene por tanto el atributo de clase `Valor.nombre`, que es el que se muestra mientras no se haya creado el atributo de instancia, y el atributo de instancia `self.nombre` que es creado cuando se llama a `ponerNombre()`. No hay ninguna variable global, por lo que sobra la instrucción `global nombre` en ese método.

### Pero ¿por qué no funciona entonces?

Si lees con detenimiento lo anterior y lo comprendes, podría quedarte la duda de por qué no está funcionando tu código, ya que en el momento que se pone `self.nombre="Daniel"` se crea un atributo de instancia que "tapa" al atributo de clase, por lo que ya no sería visible el nombre `"Alex"` a menos que usáramos `Valor.nombre`.

Esto es así, pero el problema es que estás creando un nuevo objeto `objetoValores` en cada iteración del bucle. Por tanto el objeto en que habías creado el atributo de instancia y le habías dado el valor "Daniel", se pierde en la siguiente iteración, al crearse un objeto nuevo. Ese objeto nuevo no tiene todavía atributo de instancia y por tanto se imprime el atributo de clase, que es siempre "Alex".

Answer (score 0):

La razón de esto es que cada while estás creando un nuevo objeto, por lo que se resetea cada que entra al while.

Para que funcione tal y como lo tienes simplemente tienes que pasar esta linea

```
        opcion = input()
     
        objetoValores= Valores() // <------------------
        if opcion == '1':
```

afuera del while.

Quedando tu función como.

```
def menuDeOpciones():
    bandera = True
    objetoValores= Valores()
    while bandera:
        print("1. Mostrar nombre")
        print("2. Modificar nombre")
        print("3. Salir")
        opcion = input()
        if opcion == '1':
            objetoValores.imprimiendo()
        elif opcion == '2':
            objetoValores.ponerNombre()
        elif opcion == "3":
            bandera = False

menuDeOpciones()
```

Ahora bien, la forma en que declaras variables en una clase no es la más optima, lo mejor sería crearla en un constructor

class Valores(object):

```
def __init__():
    self.nombre = 'Alex'

def ponerNombre(self):
    //global nombre esta linea está de más
    self.nombre = "Daniel"
    print("Nombre modificado")

def imprimiendo(self):
    print(self.nombre)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, podrías concluir con que si quiero que el valor de una variable pueda ser modificado en cualquier método, esta debe ser declarada dentro del constructor?